# Solving system of equations (3 unknowns, 3 equations)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So, I've been trying to solve this question but to no avail. The system of equations are as follows:

1) $x+ \frac{1}{y}=4$

2) $y+ \frac{1}{z}=1$

3) $z + \frac{1}{x}=\frac{7}{3}$

Attempt:

Using equation 1, we can rewrite it as $\frac{1}{y}=4-x \equiv y=\frac{1}{4-x}$
. Using $y=\frac{1}{4-x}$, we can substitute into equation 2 to get $\frac{1}{4-x}+\frac{1}{z}=1$ (eq. 2')

Together with equation 3, we can eliminate z by inversing equation 3 to be:

$x + \frac{1}{z}=\frac{3}{7}$

Now, we subtract both (eq. 2') and the inversed equation to get

$\frac{1}{4-x} - x = \frac{4}{7}$

However, this is going no where. The final answer should be x=$\frac{3}{2}$, y = $\frac{2}{5}$ and z = $\frac{5}{3}$.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eq. (2) implies $z=1/(1-y)$, and Eq. (1) says $y = 1/(4-x)$. Consequently, Eq. (3) becomes
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{4-x}{3-x}=\frac{7}{3} \implies 4x^2-12x+9 = (2x-3)^2 = 0 \implies x = \frac{3}{2}.$$
Consequently, $y = 1/(4-x) = 2/5$, and $z = 1/(1-y) = 5/3$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply (1) by $y$ to get:

$$xy + 1 = 4y \implies y = \frac{1}{4-x}$$

Multiply (2) by $z$ to get:

$$yz + 1 = z \implies z = \frac{1}{1-y}$$

Multiply (3) by $x$ to get:

$$zx + 1 = \frac{7z}{3} \implies x = \frac{3}{7-3z}$$

Plug the equation for $z$ into the equation for $x$. This will give you $x$ in terms of $y$. Now plug your equation for $y$ into this equation and solve for $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur input!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
x+ \frac{1}{1- \cfrac{1}{z}} =4
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+ \frac{1}{1- \cfrac{1}{\frac{7}3-\frac{1}{x}}} =4
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+ \frac{1}{1- \cfrac{3x}{7x-3}} =4
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+ \frac{7x-3}{4x-3} =4
\end{eqnarray*}
& after a little algebra $(2x-3)^2=0$.